# Convert returned CSV data to searchable / usable format in ColdFusion

Tags: csv, coldfusion

I have CSV data returned from http://api.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=IHAMPSHI46&month=3&day=25&year=2011&format=1 and need to get it into a format where I can select one of the resulting rows based on the time in the first column.

Would it be better to convert to struct/array/xml and what would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I dumped the result and it looks like the CSV file is using `<br>` tags to denote a newline so you'll have to roll your own conversion.  Here's an example that uses a UDF from [cflib](http://cflib.org):

```
<cfscript>
/**
* Transform a CSV formatted string with header column into a query object.
* 
* @param cvsString      CVS Data. (Required)
* @param rowDelim      Row delimiter. Defaults to CHR(10). (Optional)
* @param colDelim      Column delimiter. Defaults to a comma. (Optional)
* @return Returns a query. 
* @author Tony Brandner (&#116;&#111;&#110;&#121;&#64;&#98;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#100;&#110;&#101;&#114;&#115;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;)
* @version 1, September 30, 2005 
*/
function csvToQuery(csvString){
    var rowDelim = chr(10);
    var colDelim = ",";
    var numCols = 1;
    var newQuery = QueryNew("");
    var arrayCol = ArrayNew(1);
    var i = 1;
    var j = 1;

    csvString = trim(csvString);

    if(arrayLen(arguments) GE 2) rowDelim = arguments[2];
    if(arrayLen(arguments) GE 3) colDelim = arguments[3];

    arrayCol = listToArray(listFirst(csvString,rowDelim),colDelim);

    for(i=1; i le arrayLen(arrayCol); i=i+1) queryAddColumn(newQuery, arrayCol[i], ArrayNew(1));

    for(i=2; i le listLen(csvString,rowDelim); i=i+1) {
        queryAddRow(newQuery);
        for(j=1; j le arrayLen(arrayCol); j=j+1) {
            if(listLen(listGetAt(csvString,i,rowDelim),colDelim) ge j) {
                querySetCell(newQuery, arrayCol[j],listGetAt(listGetAt(csvString,i,rowDelim),j,colDelim), i-1);
            }
        }
    }
    return newQuery;
}
</cfscript>

<cfset u = "http://api.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=IHAMPSHI46&month=3&day=25&year=2011&format=1" />

<cfhttp url="#u#" result="csv" />
<!--- if you dump the result you can see that the result contains <br> tags to indicate new lines --->
<!--- 
<cfdump var="#csv.fileContent#" />
--->
<cfdump var="#csvToQuery(replace(csv.fileContent, "<br>", "", "all"))#" />
```

Comment: After posted my comment, I seen your post. Well this is perfect.

Comment: @Paul - I noticed your data has empty elements (ie ",,"). To preserve those, you can use listToArray's third parameter: `listToArray(list, delim, includeEmptyElements)` http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/functions_l_21.html

Comment: Thanks Todd.  

Incidentally, I am having a nightmare using the Q of Q.

Any reason the following would not work?

SELECT   [Time], TemperatureC, WindSpeedKMH
FROM   therightbit
WHERE  Time BETWEEN '#dateFormat(yesterday, "YYYY-MM-DD")# #timeFormat(dateAdd("h", -1, yesterday), "HH:MM")#:00' AND '#dateFormat(yesterday, "YYYY-MM-DD")# #timeFormat(dateAdd("h", 1, yesterday), "HH:MM")#:00'

Trying to select just results for current time yesterday -+ 1 hour

Comment: I get the following error:

Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "Time. Incorrect conditional expression, Expected one of [like|null|between|in|comparison] condition,

Comment: @Paul 'time' in the where clause should be [Time]

Comment: @KobbyPemson - I also tried that and get the following:

Comparison exception while executing BETWEEN.
Query Of Queries runtime error.
Type cast exception: Failed to cast object of type java.lang.String to java.util.Date.

Comment: @Paul the last line has an html comment and it gets imported. Use rereplace to get rid of it and it works. csvToQuery(rereplace(csv.fileContent, "<br>|<!--.*-->", "", "all")

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs for [cfhttp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html).  Use the name attribute and you'll get a query back from the http call.  Then you can do a query of queries on the result.

Comment: Thanks Todd.  Doing this however throws an error to say

The column name SoftwareType is invalid.

SoftwareType is the last column in the data.  Any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV result is using < br > instead of linebreak.
Use this cflib function, http://www.cflib.org/udf/CSVToQuery

Answer (score 0):

Using an H2 database (www.h2database.com) you can use the ever handy csvread function.
http://cfstuff.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-h2-database-in-coldfusion.html

```
<cfset u="http://api.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=IHAMPSHI46&month=3&day=27&year=2011&format=1"/>

<cfhttp url="#u#" result="csv" />

<cffile 
    action="write" 
    file="#ExpandPath('./w3.csv')#" 
    output="#rereplace(csv.fileContent, "<br>|<!--.*-->", "", "all")#" />


<cfquery name="w2" datasource="h3"> 
    select * from csvread('#ExpandPath('./w3.csv')#')

</cfquery>
<cfdump var=#w2# expand="no"/>

<cfset yesterday = dateadd("d",-1,now())/>
<cfquery name="w2" datasource="h3"> 

    SELECT Time, TemperatureF, WindSpeedMPH FROM csvread('#ExpandPath('./w3.csv')#')
    WHERE  Time BETWEEN '#dateFormat(yesterday, "YYYY-MM-DD")# #timeFormat(dateAdd("h", -1, yesterday), "HH:MM")#:00' AND '#dateFormat(yesterday, "YYYY-MM-DD")# #timeFormat(dateAdd("h", 1, yesterday), "HH:MM")#:00' 
</cfquery>


<cfdump var=#w2#/>
```